# Can't parse MIDI file in Python with music21 library

Tags: python, midi, audio-player, music21

I'm trying to parse some MIDI files, and nothing happens. It's strange because some files are parsed without any problem and really fast, and some just stuck. I don't know what's the problem because it doesn't show any error, a program just stuck. What are the differences between MIDI files? Why some files can't be parsed?

```
    midi = converter.parse(file) # some MIDI files just stuck here

    notes_to_parse = None

    try: 
        s2 = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        notes_to_parse = s2.parts[0].recurse() 
        ...
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in Windows, I think it's a problem about path.
Try pass the path like "c:/data/1.mid", not like "data/1.mid", I think it will be solved.